# Database design for the Lectures Scheduling for a Single Course

Tags: mysql, database-design, normalization, database-performance

I want to store the Lectures Timing information in the 3rd Normalized Database. 
The ER Diagram of the Lecture Info is as follows:

[image: ER Diagram of the Lecture Info.]

Since the `Lecture_Day` is multiple value attribute so i have designed the database as follows:

**LectureTimeTable:**

`_ID | Lecture Start Time | Lecture End Time | Lecture Loaction | Course ID FK`

**LectureDayTable:**

`_ID | Lecture Time ID FK | Course ID FK | Lecture Day`

The Queries for creating these tables are as follow:

```
CREATE TABLE lectureTimeTable (
_id INTEGER, 
startTime TEXT NOT NULL, 
endTime TEXT NOT NULL,
course_ID_FK INTEGER, 
FOREIGN KEY (course_ID_FK) REFERENCES CourseTable(_id), 
PRIMARY KEY (_id, course_ID_FK) 
);

CREATE TABLE lectureDayTable (
_id INTEGER, 
classDay INTEGER NOT NULL, 
classTime_ID_FK INTEGER, 
course_ID_FK INTEGER, 
FOREIGN KEY (course_ID_FK, classTime_ID_FK) 
REFERENCES lectureTimeTable(course_ID_FK, _id),
PRIMARY KEY (_id, classTime_ID_FK, course_ID_FK)
);
```

Now the user add new schedule for the course by giving Lecture Location, Start Time, End Time and Lecture Day(s). I am separately adding this information in the tables as follows:

```
INSERT INTO lectureTimeTable VALUES (1, "12:00", "1:00", 1);

// and for inserting the days i am using a for loop as follows, Here the
for(i=0; i<=selectedDays.length();i++){
INSERT INTO lectureDayTable VALUES (1, selectedDays[i], 1, 1);
}
```

I am troubling with adding/retrieving data from these tables so i just want to ensure that my database design is not bad.

Thanks.

Comment: its easy if you design a table which has records for each block in the week. (block of lecture times) assuming you operate on a standard schedule. then you can just assign lectures to each block

Comment: can you please further explain it?

Comment: sure it will take about 20 minutes for me to type it up for you ok

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image: Database Design]

You can design a table called `timetable` this table can hold your weekly schedule. You can fill it up completely with a 2 dimensional array of time blocks and class rooms. This allows you to print the schedule on a screen without having to calculate a grid. grid is already preloaded to the table. Then from a table of `lecture` you can assign them to the `timetable`

Comment: Thanks @DevZerO this logic more efficient than mine.